# Cannot open certain websites when SOCKS 5 DNS proxy is enabled on Firefox

Tags: debian, proxy, firefox, socks

Using the terminal, I run the following.

```
ssh admin@1.2.3.4 -i ~/.ssh/admin -N -D 9090
```

Firefox is configured as follow.

[image: Firefox SOCKS 5]

Many websites work just fine, but certain ones fails and the following error is thrown on the terminal.

```
channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

My research points to a DNS problem as indicated by running `tail auth.log` on the server.

```
error: connect_to ipleak.net: unknown host (Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use more reliable DNS servers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sometimes the answer is so obvious I don’t even consider it! Switched to `1.1.1.1` and the issue is fixed.Thanks for your help. Mind blown that the DNS servers of DigitalOcean are that shitty.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Want to submit an answer or should I answer my own question?

Comment: I have more points than I know what to do with. Feel free to answer it yourself. You did most of the work anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael’s suggestion, I narrowed the issue down to DNS.

Switching from DigitalOcean’s DNS servers to `1.1.1.1` fixed the issue.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```